# How to center JPanel on the screen

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to do something similar to "game of life" using JPanel, the problem is that it appears in left upper side of the screen. My question is how can I make it screen centered.
P.S I also tried creating JFrame and adding JPanel to it, but it just created JFrame and JPanel separately. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Cell[][] cellMatrix;
private Options op;

Animation(Options received) {

this.op = received;
this.cellMatrix = new Cell[op.getNumberOfCells()][op.getNumberOfCells()];
this.setBackground(op.getBackGroundColour());

}

Timer time = new Timer(5,this);

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < op.getNumberOfCells() ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < op.getNumberOfCells(); j++) {    
        Cell c1 = new Cell();

        if(c1.getVal() % 2 == 0) {

            g.setColor(op.getAliveCellColour());
            g.fillRect(i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10);
            c1.changeStat(0);
            cellMatrix[i][j]= c1;

        }
        else {

            g.setColor(op.getDeadCellColour());
            g.fillRect(i * 10,j * 10, 10, 10);
            c1.changeStat(1);
            cellMatrix[i][j]= c1;

        }
        }
    }
    time.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < op.getNumberOfCells() ; i=i+2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < op.getNumberOfCells()-1; j++){
            int sum = cellMatrix[i][j].getVal() + cellMatrix[i+1][j].getVal()+ cellMatrix[i][j+1].getVal() + cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].getVal();
            switch(sum) {
            case(2) : continue;
            case(0) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(1) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(4) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(3) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();blockShift(i,j);break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < op.getNumberOfCells()-1 ; i=i+2) {
        for (int j = 1; j < op.getNumberOfCells()-1; j++){
            int sum = cellMatrix[i][j].getVal() + cellMatrix[i+1][j].getVal()+ cellMatrix[i][j+1].getVal() + cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].getVal();
            switch(sum) {
            case(2) : continue;
            case(0) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(1) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(4) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();break;
            case(3) : cellMatrix[i][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i][j+1].reverseState(); cellMatrix[i+1][j+1].reverseState();blockShift(i,j);break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void blockShift(int i, int j) {

    Cell temp1 = new Cell(this.cellMatrix[i][j]);
    this.cellMatrix[i][j]=this.cellMatrix[i+1][j+1];
    this.cellMatrix[i+1][j+1] = temp1;
    Cell temp2 = new Cell(this.cellMatrix[i+1][j]);
    this.cellMatrix[i+1][j] = this.cellMatrix[i][j+1];
    this.cellMatrix[i][j+1] = temp2;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    time.setDelay(1000);
    repaint();
}
```

}

Here is the part where I try to use JFrame:

```
public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Cell[][] cellMatrix;
private Options op;
private JFrame jf;

Animation(Options received) {

jf = new JFrame("Example");
jf.setSize(860, 640);
jf.setLocationByPlatform(false);

this.op = received;
this.cellMatrix = new Cell[op.getNumberOfCells()][op.getNumberOfCells()];
this.setBackground(op.getBackGroundColour());
jf.add(this);
jf.setVisible(true);

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to let the frame appear at the center of your screen, you can set the location by:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Note that you would want to invoke the above ***after*** you set the size (or `pack()`) your frame.

Comment: ok thanks! but what if I want the JPanel to apper in the center of the screen, or the JFrame to have the JPanel inside, frame.add(this) doesn't seems to work. Is it because I'm using extend JPanel?

Comment: @Keselme Yes, you will add the JPanel into your JFrame. The JPanel can't display by itself. You need to add it to a container like JFrame to display it. You did the right thing to extends to JPanel instead of a JFrame. Just add your customized JPanel to a JFrame and display the JFrame.

Comment: `frame.add(this) doesn't seems to work` Try this after your `jf.add(this)` : `jf.pack();`, `jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`, `jf.setVisible(true);`. Remove other codes such as `setSize()` and `setLocationByPlatform()`  for the frame which may be conflicting. Usually I wouldn't set the size for the frame manually. But use pack() to decide the size for itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JPanel: you add it to a JFrame:

Then to center the JFrame on the screen you do

```
  Toolkit it=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Dimension d=it.getScreenSize();
  int w=jf.getWidth(), h=jf.getHeight();
  jf.setLocation(d.width/2-w/2, d.height/2-h/2);
```